# Как открыть список контактов при нажатии на ссылку в HTML?

Tags: java, html, android, webview

У меня есть веб-страница, на которой расположена ссылка вида `<a href="..."/>`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на неё открывался список контактов телефона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно переопределить `WebViewClient`

```
private class Client extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("ваша ссылка")){
                Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

При инициализации WebView назначить его
`webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());`

Если контакт будет выбираться то вызывать `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Воспользовался вашим способом. Все прекрасно работает, спасибо.

Comment: Да на здоровье)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в манифест в активити такой фильтр:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

При этом будет запускаться ваша активити при клике на ссылку www.youtube.com. А дальше уже можно показывать книгу контактов.

Comment: ну это же явный хак :)

Comment: @Barmaley почему? Это довольно распространенная практика: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213

Comment: Ну там идет речь идет не о линке на youtube.com, а вообще о кастомных схемах. Под хаком я имел ввиду как раз youtube

Comment: @Barmaley ну то я для примера